# How to remove travelled path from google map in Swift

Tags: swift, google-maps, google-directions-api

I write below code for removing the travelled path by a user but it will not worked as expected some time it will remove correctly and some time not. I observe one thing in this case after debugging a lot that is when we call direction API and getting route points for creating path then distance is always different between 2 successive points for example we have10 route coordinates between 2 points but all the coordinate have different distance from previous one.

```
func updateTravelledPath(currentLoc: CLLocationCoordinate2D){
        var index = 0
        
        if let counter = self.route?.path?.count() {
            
            for i in 0..<counter {
              
                let pathLat = Double(self.route?.path?.coordinate(at: i).latitude ?? 0.0).rounded(toPlaces: 5)
                let pathLong = Double(self.route?.path?.coordinate(at: i).longitude ?? 0.0).rounded(toPlaces: 5)
                
                let currentLat = Double(currentLoc.latitude).rounded(toPlaces: 5)
                let currentLong = Double(currentLoc.longitude).rounded(toPlaces: 5)
                
                if currentLat <= pathLat || currentLong <= pathLong{
                    index = Int(i)
                    break   //Breaking the loop when the index found
                }
            
            }

            //Creating new path from the current location to the destination
            let newPath = GMSMutablePath()
            for i in index..<Int(counter){
                if let cordd = self.route?.path?.coordinate(at: UInt(i)) {
                    newPath.add(cordd)
                }
            }
            self.route?.path = newPath
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                for item in self.route?.polyLine ?? [GMSPolyline]() {
                    item.map = nil
                }
                self.route?.polyLinee = nil
                self.route?.polyLinee?.map = nil
                
                self.route?.polyLinee = GMSPolyline(path: self.route?.path)
                self.route?.polyLinee?.strokeWidth = 5.0
                self.route?.polyLinee?.strokeColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.02352941176, green: 0.5725490196, blue: 0.4666666667, alpha: 1)
                self.route?.polyLine = [GMSPolyline(path: self.route?.path)]
                self.route?.polyLinee?.map = self.mapView
                self.mapView.reloadInputViews()
            }
        }
    }  
    
extension Double {
    // Rounds the double to decimal places value
    func rounded(toPlaces places:Int) -> Double {
        let divisor = pow(10.0, Double(places))
        return (self * divisor).rounded() / divisor
    }
}

**Thanks in advance**
```

Comment: Have you tried calling `GMSMapView.clear()` which allows you to clear all markup that has been added to the map, including polylines? Here is the link to the [public documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/reference/interface_g_m_s_map_view#a28e6b8aeb7c8dc9025dc001f2a5d2c9b) for your reference.

Comment: Thanks for answering, Yes I know that but it will remove all the overlay items from map but I need to remove only covered path from source to destination.